# Are there Python 2.4 bindings for WebDriver?

Tags: python, webdriver

Are there Python 2.4 bindings for [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted)?

My team is stuck using Python 2.4.  Currently we're using [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29)'s WebDriver to do web testing, but we use [JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/) to interface with Java bindings.  This has resulted in us being unable to wait for pages to load, which means we use sleeps instead, which dramatically increases the amount of time it takes to run a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemingly no, but there is a version of JPype for Python 2.4, and JPype can be used to access the Java bindings to webdriver, so in that manner python 2.4 can be used with webdriver.